# Amplitude encoding: distinction between negative and positive real values

Tags: qiskit, fidelity, swap-test

I want to encode two vectors into qubits and compute a distance between them that corresponds/is proportional to the euclidian distance of the real vectors.

The encoding I use is

- A) qiskit `initialize` method

```
def get_encoding_circuit(*vv): 
    
    sz = int(np.log2(len(vv[0])))
    
    qc = QuantumCircuit(len(vv)*sz)

    for i, v in enumerate(vv):
        qc.initialize(v, range(i*sz, (i+1)*sz))
    
    return qc
```

and

- B) amplitude encoding as shown [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-85474-1.pdf)

The distance metric I use is given by the overlap from

- I) qiskit's `state_fidelity` method and
- II) a Swap Test circuit.

For example in $\mathbb{R^2}$, $u$ and $v$ given as

$$
u = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad
v = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

are encoded as

$$
|u\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} 0.70711 \\  0.70711 \end{bmatrix} \quad
|v\rangle = \begin{bmatrix} - 0.70711 \\ - 0.70711 \end{bmatrix}
$$

The problem I have (with any combination of A), B) I), II)) is that $|u\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$ have an overlap of 1, so are equivalent. The reason is that the encoding of $v$ is equal to the encoding of $u$, just with a global phase added,

s.t. the fidelity (as computed by qiskit) for example is

$$
| \langle u|v\rangle |^2 = 1.0
$$

but
$\text{dist_eucl}(u,v)$ is far from 0.

What encoding can I use that will produce distinct qubits for positive and negative real inputs?

Edit/Followup:

I finally used the statepreparation described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0411)
For real vectors in the range $[-1,1]$ I obtain quantum distances corresponding to euclidian distances:
[image: quantum distance]

Comment: The behaviour of Qubits is best described with vectors; but those vectors are probability amplitudes that describe a data register; they do not correspond to Euclidean Distance in any clear way; even when thinking about Qubits using a Bloch Sphere. How would your algorithm work calculate the distance between (1,0) and (5,0)?

Comment: Undoubtedly this task can be done using a Quantum Computer...however this simplification of trying to encode a real vector as a single qubit likely will not lead anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, global phase is a problem here. One option that you *could* pursue (I'm not claiming it's a good option) is to use a two-qubit encoding. Let's say you want to encode a vector $u\in\mathbb{C}^2$ (you asked about real, which is obviously a simplifying case)
$$
u=\left[\begin{array}{c}
ae^{i\theta_1} \\ be^{i\theta_2}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where $a,b\geq 0$. You could encode this as
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\left[\begin{array}{c}
a \\ be^{i(\theta_2-\theta_1)}
\end{array}\right]\otimes \left[\begin{array}{c}
\cos2\theta_1 \\ \sin2\theta_1
\end{array}\right]
$$

In the case where your vectors are real, I believe this gives the same inner product as the original vector, up to the effect of the normalisation factor.